# WordPress Shortcode adding attributes

Tags: html, string, wordpress, shortcode

I'm writing a shortcode function for WP. Inside the function I have the $content (in this case an image). I need to be able to add a couple attributes to that content and return it in a string, like so:

```
function Shortcode( $atts, $content=null ){
   if(!is_null($content){
      return '<div class="wrapper">'. $content .'</div>'
   }
}
```

Currently, just the image is getting spit back, but I need to somehow modify it and add a couple attributes before adding it to the string above.

I need to do something like this:

```
function Shortcode( $atts, $content=null ){
   if(!is_null($content){
      // CONVERT $CONTENT TO STRING
      $content_html=somefunction($content) 

      echo $content_html; // <img src='....' />

      return '<div class="wrapper">'. $content_html .'</div>'
   }
}
```

Comment: The variable `$content` will always contain the image tag? Show your example output

Comment: Can you show the function code you have currently and also the output that is currently received. You should be able to make `$content` an array and just add to the array but we'd need to see the current code.

Comment: I've updated the question..not sure if that helps... basically I'm trying to "edit" $content and cannot figure out how to first convert it into a string equivalent to its html (<img src="...."), so that I could then modify that string with the img attributes I need on it.